# Google Places API rankBy

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm coding JS app which will do this things

Find my location(I did this)
Find specified ATM(well I didn't figure how to find around my radius)
To list all found ATMs and sort them by distance

For this I need rankBy but I don't know how to use it.I looked on internet,where nearly everyone talks about that but no one don't show how to use.

Does someone can help mi to set my radius and in that radius to show ATMs and sort them by distance?

here is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Animations</title>
    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
         * element that contains the map. */
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>


    function initMap() {
        var map, infoWindow,service,infoWindow1;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 12
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };


                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                });
                marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);

                function toggleBounce() {
                    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                        marker.setAnimation(null);
                    } else {
                        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    }
                }
            }, function () {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }


        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }

        infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        map.addListener('idle', performSearch);

        function performSearch() {
            var request = {
                bounds: map.getBounds(),
                keyword: 'telenor atm',

            };
            service.radarSearch(request, callback);
        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.error(status);
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
                addMarker(result);
            }
        }

        function addMarker(place) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                icon: {
                    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/circle.png',
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 37)
                }
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                service.getDetails(place, function (result, status) {
                    if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.error(status);
                        return;
                    }
                    infoWindow1.setContent(result.name);
                    infoWindow1.open(map,marker);
                });
            });
        }
    }


</script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCW8gRR1ITJDx4F-rVpkBSetftu32XO2P0&callback=initMap&libraries=places,visualization" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```